# Usage of ergo (conjunction and not prefix)

Tags: usage, conjonctions, latin

According to https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/ergo/

> Ergo signifie "donc, par conséquent, ainsi" ; ce terme n'est quasiment plus usité dans le langage courant.
> Exemple : Je t'avais prévenue que je resterai ici le temps que tu te sentes mieux. Ce qui est le cas aujourd'hui. Ergo, je fais ma valise et je rentre chez moi. Tu es prête à vivre seule, je le sais, fais-moi confiance.

Is there an explanation for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ergo* est un mot latin qui n'a pas été conservé en français. Il n'est pas mentionné dans le [*Dictionnaire de l'ancienne langue française et de tous ses dialectes du IXe au XVe siècle* de Frédéric Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/ergo) ni dans le [*Dictionnaire du moyen français*](http://www2.atilf.fr/dmf/).

Dire que *ergo* « n'est quasiment plus usité » est un peu trompeur : il a arrêté d'être utilisé à une époque où la langue française n'existait pas encore en tant que telle. Je ne connais pas d'autre langue moderne qui ait conservé ce mot (italien, espagnol, portugais, roumain, …), ce qui indique probablement que le mot a disparu très tôt. Les différentes langues romanes ont adopté d'autres mots. En portugais, en espagnol et en italien, on trouve (entre autres) [*portanto*](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/portanto)/[*por lo tanto*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/por_lo_tanto)/[*pertanto*](https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/pertanto). Le français a aussi cette étymologie sous la forme [*partant*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/partant#Conjonction), mais ce mot est rare depuis plusieurs siècles même si certains l'utilisent encore. En français et en italien, on a [*donc*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/donc)/[*dunque*](https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/dunque).

Le mot *ergo* a été réintroduit par des francophones pour qui c'était un mot latin. Au début, [*ergo*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ergo) était un moyen de se moquer des raisonnements énoncés par des gens éduqués, mais pas forcément intelligents. Quelqu'un qui éprouve le besoin d'utiliser des mots latins dans un raisonnement, en général, c'est quelqu'un qui récite des choses apprises dans une langue étrangère sans forcément les comprendre. De nos jours, *ergo* a largement perdu son aspect de moquerie, mais reste rare.

Comment: Par exemple, Decartes a dit en français « Je pense *donc* je suis » et jamais « Cogito ergo sum » comme on dit. Il a trouvé plus commode et répandu de le dire en français pour que tout le monde comprenne.